# How can a user update another model's table's values using a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I have a user that contains their addresses. Now, I have another table, called search address, that contains a search_address.

This should be a one to one relationship, where a user can only create one search address on the search address table.

I want it so a user can submit a form, and create, in the address search table, a search_address. Afterwards, I want to callback that search_address's latitude and longitude (I'm using the geocoder gem).

This is the code I have so far:

Schema:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "address"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
  end
  create_table "search_addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.string   "search_address"
    t.float    "search_latitude"
    t.float    "search_longitude"
  end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode

end
```

Search Address model:

```
class SearchAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  geocoded_by :search_address, :latitude => :search_latitude, :longitude => :search_longitude

end
```

My current view (I based this answer off another Stack answer, but it isn't working):

```
<%= semantic_form_for @users do |f| %>

<%= fields_for @user.searchaddresses do |g| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= g.label :search_address, 'Search Address' %>
      <br/>
      <%= g.text_field :search_address, :class => "form-control" %>
    </div>

  <%= f.submit 'Save Search Address' %>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Also, my intended view would display something like this:

```
<%= @user.searchaddress.latitude %>
<%= @user.searchaddress.longitude %>
```

Based on this information, what should I do to the form so a user can add in one search address, and then have another view show the latitude and longitude of this search address?

Comment: have a look at this https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I do not understand what you are after. Would you be able to add some clarify to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 => Use `Nested Attributes` for User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many : search_addresses, dependent: :destroy
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :search_addresses
end
```

2 => Fix Typo

```
<%= semantic_form_for @user do |f| %>

  <%= fields_for @user.search_addresses do |g| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= g.label :search_address, 'Search Address' %>
      <br/>
      <%= g.text_field :search_address, :class => "form-control" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit 'Save Search Address' %>
<% end %>
```

3 => users_controller.rb

```
def update
  #fetch user to be updated along with search_addresses
  @user.update(update_user_params)
  #after update
end

private
  def update_user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(search_addresses_attributes: [:search_address])
  end
```

References: - [Ruby on Rails Nested Attributes](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes),

[Active Record Nested Attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)